# Add minor gridlines

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, gridlines

But I can't seem to figure out how to show minor gridlines in my plots with a seaborn style.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sbn

x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)
y = np.sin(x)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.scatter(x, y)

ax.grid(b=True, which='major')
ax.grid(b=True, which='minor')
```

[image]

Any thoughts here?  Also any thoughts on how to adjust the style of the Seaborn gridlines that do show up...in particular, I'd love to make them narrower.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Wound up combining CT Zhu's answer with tcaswell's hint:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sbn

x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)
y = np.sin(x)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)

ax.scatter(x, y)
ax.get_xaxis().set_minor_locator(mpl.ticker.AutoMinorLocator())
ax.get_yaxis().set_minor_locator(mpl.ticker.AutoMinorLocator())
ax.grid(b=True, which='major', color='w', linewidth=1.0)
ax.grid(b=True, which='minor', color='w', linewidth=0.5)
```

[image]

Comment: Can you open an issue on the seaborn github about this? You shouldn't need to style the minor gridlines yourself, but I think that's an oversight in the current code.

Comment: breadcrumb: https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/110 (more or less unresolved)

Answer (score 11):

That's because the minor ticks are not yet defined, so we need to add for example:

```
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(0,8)-0.5, minor=True)
ax.set_yticks([-1.25, -0.75, -0.25,0.24,0.75,1.25], minor=True)
```

[image]

Comment: It is better to `ax.get_xaxis().set_minor_locator(...)`