# How the number of grid lines can be increased in seaborn?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, gridview, seaborn

I have such a piece of code for plotting:

```
sns.set_style("darkgrid")
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)    
        
x = np.arange(10)
ax.plot(x, x)
```

And it gives me:

[image]

How the number of grid lines can be increased in seaborn, to make it denser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on this question : [add minor gridlines to matplotlib plot using seaborn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21923463/add-minor-gridlines-to-matplotlib-plot-using-seaborn), you can do it like that.

```
sns.set_style("darkgrid")
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)    
    
x = np.arange(10)
ax.plot(x, x)
ax.get_xaxis().set_minor_locator(mpl.ticker.AutoMinorLocator())
ax.get_yaxis().set_minor_locator(mpl.ticker.AutoMinorLocator())
ax.grid(b=True, which='major', color='w', linewidth=1.0)
ax.grid(b=True, which='minor', color='w', linewidth=0.5)
```

You obtain this figure :

[image]